# Probability - An urn with twenty balls (10 are black/ other 10 are red) pick three.

Tags: probability

Urn with ten red balls and ten black balls, what is the probability that you will get balls of both colors if you draw three times without replacement?

I created a tree with all the possible combinations (BBR, BRB, and etc.). There are eight variables and only two of them would not work BBB/RRR. So wouldn't be the answer be 75%?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are drawing **without replacement**, the $8$ events you are thinking about are not all equally likely.  If, for example, you have drawn $2$ balls, and gotten BB, the probability the next one is a B is slightly lower than if your first two balls were AA, or AB. Your reasoning would be perfectly correct if the drawing were done with replacement.

I would probably attack the problem like this. The probability of BBB is $\frac{10}{20}\cdot\frac{9}{19}\cdot\frac{8}{18}$.

By symmetry the probability of RRR is the same. So the probability you will get a monochrome set of balls is $q=2\cdot\frac{10}{20}\cdot\frac{9}{19}\cdot\frac{8}{18}$.

The probability there will be some colour variation is $1-q$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $10\cdot{9}\cdot{10}$ or some permutation?  At some point you have to pick from the other color when there are 10 in there.

Comment: Never mind...  I saw the 'monochrome'...

Comment: Another way to think about this is to pick a ball, then pick two more balls of the same color, so $\frac{9}{19}\frac{8}{18}$, which is your expression ($2 \times \frac{10}{20} = 1$). This differs from Christopher Enrst's answer. (87/114 ?)

Comment: @snarski: Your method of obtaining what I called $q$ is nicer than mine, since it takes maximal advantage of the symmetry.

Comment: @snarski, yours should be $2\times\frac{8}{4\cdot{19}}=\frac{16}{76}$ which completely agrees with my complementary method!

Comment: @ChristopherErnst You are right! I don't know how to count.

Comment: it's okay...my wife always yells at me because she throws out calculations and I get them wrong.  She says, "you went to school for math!" and I say "It's not like that...." but I lose every time....

Answer (score 0):

The key here is 'without replacement'.  To pick the three balls, the scheme will always be two of one color and one of the other.  Thus, we have probability
$$\frac{10\cdot{9}\cdot{10}}{20\cdot{19}\cdot{18}}$$
There are 6 out of 8 ways to do this so the answer is
$$6\times\frac{10\cdot{9}\cdot{10}}{20\cdot{19}\cdot{18}}=\frac{60}{76}$$